# make: automatic execution of targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my project, I have a set of programs that are build from sources:

```
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
TARGETS   = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(BIN_DIR)/%,$(SRC_FILES))
```

My build target is simple, and works fine:

```
all: $(TARGETS)
    @echo "- Done target $@"
```

Now, I want a `run` target so that all these programs are run from the shell on request. Say, if I have 3 files, I want make to run automatically:

```
>$ ./test1
>$ ./test2
>$ ./test3
```

Or

```
>$ ./test1 && ./test2 && ./test3
```

I tried this:

```
run: $(TARGETS)
   $(addsuffix && ,$(TARGETS))
```

That generates the following command:

```
./test1&& ./test2&&
```

but it fails, due to the trailing `&&`

(Of course, I want these to be generated automatically as there can be 3... or 30.)

**Edit**: actually, the `&&` separator is not required, so something like this:

```
>$ ./test1; ./test2; ./test3;
```

will be fine too.

Comment: For the record, and besides the answers below, `$(addsuffix ; ,$(TARGETS))` does the job too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternatives to Basile Starynkevitch's entirely correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001436/258523) there are (at least) two other options as well.

You can avoid the need to run an unnecessary command (builtin though it might be) to end the list by manually pulling off the first entry (this may in fact be more costly then the shell builtin though).

```
run: $(TARGETS)
        $< $(addprefix &&,$(wordlist 2,$(words $^),$^))
```

A better option I think, assuming that connecting the commands with `&&` isn't a necessity would be to use `$(foreach)` to generate the command to be run.

```
run: $(TARGETS)
        $(foreach t,$^,$t;)
```

The trailing `;` in that is **crucial** as the output from `$(foreach)` is a single line and you need `;` to terminate each shell command (or it is seen as one long command with arguments).

Answer (score 2):

Have some `.PHONY` line near start of `Makefile` with

```
 .PHONY: all run
```

You might have

```
 run: $(TARGETS)
     $(addsuffix && ,$(TARGETS)) true
```

but it is a dirty trick.

Maybe you want to produce the output of `test2` into `test2.out` then you might have

```
 TESTSCRIPTS= $(wildcard test*[0-9])
 run: $(patsubst %, %.out, $(TESTSCRIPTS))

 test%.out: test%
 # here some command to run the test%
```

Comment: Thanks. Hah! I like the `true` trick. Second solution can't work, as my filenames are arbitrary.

Comment: Alternatively `$< $(addprefix &&,$(wordlist 2,$(words $^),$^))` or `$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$t;)` though that latter changes the semantics a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Etan Reisner, smart, I like the second one as the `&&` isn't really mandatory, so the `foreach` seems to be the best approach. Consider adding as answer ?

Comment: You can use `;` in any of these answers instead of `&&`. The benefit of `;` is that it is valid in a trailing position where `&&` isn't so you don't need the `true` or `wordlist` games to make it work and can use the simpler `foreach` solution.